# Intel Server System SR1630GP - Fan speed and noise proble m

Tags: boot, fan, noise

I have a problem with a newly acquired  SR1630GP. Fans won't slow down after boot.

As expected, they start at full speed during startup, but keep at this rate even after the OS properly launched. I suspect this being kind of ACPI-related but I could find no solution to my problem by myself.

Here is my configuration:

- Intel SR1630GP Server System with S3420GPLC motherboard
- Intel Xeon 3430 CPU
- Kingston KVR1333D3D8R9SK2/4G - 2x2Go, PC10600 DDR3 (On the compatibility list)
- All this runs Fedora 15 as OS.

The system is in a suitable place, with good airflow and average room temperature.

The two fans and the CPU heatsink are those provided with the system, and were correctly mounted according to the documents provided with the system.

Some relevant BIOS settings:

- CPU suspend states C3 and C6 are deactivated (I read that it could cause problems)
- Fans throttling mode is on "Auto", with the "Acoustic" setting.
- Altitude entered is "under 300m", which is correct.

I understand that this system is meant to be in a server room and isn't particularly silent, but there is obviously something wrong in this case.

Comment: Did this system ever work correctly?

Comment: It's a new system, and it runs very well. It boots, loads the OS, and I can SSH into it, install and run applications... The only problem is the noise, really. We don't have a separate room for servers, and the guy working next to it is slowly getting insane. Plus I'm worrying about the constant full-speed of the fans reducing their lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we bought a SC5650UP chassis. (6U)

The advice here is: don't go for 1U or 2U rackable stuff if it's meant to be installed in a small office, in the same room than people.
There is only so much you can do about the noise of 40mm fans.

A more technical one: if you ever have a fan speed / noise problem with an Intel Server, update FRU/SDR. With the integrated EFI shell, it's really easy, and will do wonders for your server. (In the limit of what its physical specs can do)